# i want to display the data from database after registering an user but the data shown is blank

Tags: ionic2

I am trying to register a user as a manager or user(roles), for both roles i am using two different tables the data is registering successfully in database after clicking register button i have  set the root page as home page which consisting of managers i used set root method on nav controller object   but the data is not displaying after the page is navigated. But after killing the app and opening again the data is shown in the page any answers??

```
register.ts file-
   this.database.openDatabase({
      name: "data.db",
      location: "default"
    }).then(() => {
      alert("database Opened");
      this.database.executeSql("INSERT INTO Managers(name,email,Password,Photo) VALUES(?,?,?,?)", [name, email, password, this.base64Image])
        .then((data) => {
          alert(JSON.stringify(data));
          alert("Registered Successfully into Managers");
          this.navCtrl.setRoot(Page1);
        }, (error) => {
          console.log("Unable To Insert Data into role1: ", error);
          alert("Unable To Insert Data");
        })
    }, (error) => {
      console.log("Unable To Open Database: ", error);
      alert("Unable to Open Database");
    });


 Page1.ts-
      this.database.openDatabase({
      name: "data.db",
      location: "default"
    }).then(() => {
      this.database.executeSql("SELECT * from Managers", {})
        .then((data) => {


this.Managers = [];
          if (data.rows.length > 0) {
            let managerLocal = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
              managerLocal.push({ password: data.rows.item(i).Password, id: data.rows.item(i).id, name: data.rows.item(i).name, email: data.rows.item(i).email, photo: data.rows.item(i).Photo });
            }
            this.Managers = managerLocal;
          }
        }, (error) => {
          console.log("Unable To Retrieve Data from Managers: ", error);
          alert("Unable To get Data");
        })
    }, (error) => {
      console.log("Unable To Open Database: ", error);
      alert("Unable to Open Database");
    });

    Page1.html-
      <ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
    <h1 class="managers">Managers List</h1>
    <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let manager of Managers">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-avatar item-left>
          <img [src]="manager.photo" *ngIf="manager.photo" />
        </ion-avatar>
        <h2>{{manager.name}}</h2>
        <p>{{manager.email}}</p>
        <button ion-button *ngIf="Role == '1' || Role == '0' 
            (click)="editDetails(manager)">
          <ion-icon name="create"></ion-icon>
      </button>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item-options>
        <button ion-button *ngIf="Role == '0'" (click)="deleteData(manager)">
        <ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon>Delete
      </button>
      </ion-item-options>
    </ion-item-sliding>
  </ion-list>
  <ion-fab right bottom>
    <button ion-fab *ngIf="Role == '0'" (click)="register()">
        <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
      </button>
  </ion-fab>

  <ion-label class="display" [style.visibility]="((Managers == null || Managers.length==0)) ? 'visible' : 'hidden'">No Data Available</ion-label>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: where's your page navigation code?

Comment: and where you have declared those methods? Inside the `constructor` or else?

Comment: I have declared them in the constructor

Comment: The page is navigated when setroot method is called

Comment: any console error messages on `Page1`?

Comment: No error messages

Comment: any fix for this problem??

Comment: as a test can you do this.remove all the database related stuff on `page1` and see whether `page1` is loading correctly first.If that works then you have a problem on DB operations.

Comment: actually the list is displaying fine after killing the app i don't think there is wrong with db operations.

Comment: i will give a try

Comment: i tried placing the db operations in onInit() method even though no luck

Comment: No, you have to remove that completely and just see whether page1 is being loaded.that is it? just as a test.we need to find out the issue first.my strong feeling where you have a problem with the db operation.see that and let me know.

Comment: yes the page is loading..

Comment: i just posted my html once go through it please..

Comment: very difficult to say that the issue without debugging the code.Is this sample(test) project or a commercial one? If it's a sample one then you can put this on Git and we can paly with it.

Comment: its a sample i will post the repo..

Comment: Great.After posting please download it from your repo and check whether is it working when you run `ionic serve`.

Answer (score 0):

The database is already open in the register.ts file. When you make setRoot, you are trying to open the database again which I think would be the problem. Put your database initiation logic in a resource file or a Provider (in angular2 language) and import your resource in both your hoepage as well as registerpage and use the db instance from that to directly perform insert and select queries.

//Sample db initiatialisation in resource :

```
export class Resource{
   db : any

   getDbInstance(){
        //Getting instance logic
       return new Promise((resove, reject){
            if(this.db){ //Checking if db is already initialised
           return resolve(this.db)
       }
       else{ //else initialise it and return the instance
            this.database.openDatabase({
                 name: "data.db",
                 location: "default"
            }, (dbInstance)=>{ this.db = dbInstance; return resolve(dbInstance) })
       }
      })
   }

}
```

this method will be called like a promise from the two pages. So, In essence, the db is opened only once and the same instance is used across the application. I wont be able to give you entire code tailored to your needs so, do your research on how to implement this for your project. Cheers